# Transfer data model tables from sql to csv

Tags: sql, csv, foreign-keys, primary-key, datamodel

I have lots of sql tables. The tables are "dependent" , i.e. constraints on foreign keys are defined between the tables.
I need to transfer the tables from sql to csv. What is correct way to do that:

- Define tables exactly as they are defined in sql? (What should I do with the foreign keys?)
- Try to generate other tables by joining the existing ones based on foreign keys in order to hide the foreign keys dependencies?

May be there are other options? What are the pros and cons ?
Thanks,

Note:This is need for another application that run some anylitics on the data

Comment: The best way to do this depends on the intended use of the csv data.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - there is an application which reads the data and run analitics (machine learning) on the data. new data is inserted oce a day to the tables

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a view in SQL which contains all information from all tables you need in your CSV later. 
The view already implements the dependencies (link of two rows from different tables) and linkes all together in one table.

It would be way easier than your second proposal to create a new table because the view will do all the work for you.

I guess you will need your dependencies.
So you should not ignore them.
Here a quick example how they work:
Lets say you have 2 Tables the first one is named persons and the second one is cars. In the persons table you have 3 columns: ID, Name, Age. In the second one you have ID, Car. To see which person has which car you just check which id from the first table has which value for car in the second one.
If you link them together in a view the result is one single table with the columns ID, Person, Age, Car.

Same does the view.
Later you can simply export the view to CSV.

Maybe I can help you better if you define your needs a bit more detailed.
What kind of data is in your tables, how are they linked(what are the primary/secondary keys).

Comment: can you please explain why? and comment/ compare to proposals I had

Comment: In CSV there is no way to show the dependencies between the tables. And if u want to  join data from one into another the most simple way is to create a view. SQL will generate a single table and joins all the data for you. If you need to split them later you can do it in code and "restore" the dependencies as you want them to be. But to get all the data from SQL the easiest way in my eyes is to create a view.

Comment: Show the dependencies? I am not sure I indeed need them. I can just give the same name to columns...is it good? how the dependecies are "used" in practis? BTW on sql all dependecies i have are defined as ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Comment: Why should I link them together? Why not to leave 2 tables as is? My needs - to run the same queries and insert data - the tables should be in csv

Comment: Of course you dont have to link them. If needed you can export each table as it is. Just run the queries and then save the result as csv. But the more tables you have the more csv-files you will have in the end. Even if you create a view this will not change any of your insert routines ...